# Where can I install termcap from?

Tags: apt, aptitude

From apt-get or aptitude there's just termcap-compact, but I still see "no termcap library found" when trying to install my software (a development kit from another enterprise).

This happens just on my computer.

[This page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html) has a .tar.gz, but looks like it's the source, I how to install it..

Where can I install termcap from?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For libraries and header files, you have to install the developer packages, often the package name with the `-dev` prefix appended.

The termcap library and headers are part of the [libncurses5-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/amd64/libncurses5-dev/filelist) package, which can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Additionally, if you just want to build a newer version of a package, consider using the `build-dep` command to fetch all known dependencies for the package that is currently in the repositories. For instance:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nmon
```

Would install the following packages (if not already installed):

```
debhelper libncurses5-dev hardening-wrapper
```

Comment: @jmunsch I've changed the link to something version-independent. Feel free to edit my post(s) if necessary.